# Centering a Horizontal List in a Bootstrap 3 Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, list, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I have tried many things but can't seem to get the two footer lists to center. Admittedly I'm a beginner and probably making some basic logical mistakes. Please hold my hand a little and help me out before I lose it. I have followed many of the standard solutions but I must be doing something that conflicts or my targeting is wrong. Thank You for any help. Jacob

This is contained in the Bootstrap 3 framework within fluid container. I ultimately want the the two footer lists to center within a responsive design.

You can see the site here. [Jacob Norwood Heroku App](http://jacobnorwood.herokuapp.com/)

CSS/LESS Footer Code

```
footer {
    margin: 25px 0 25px 0;
}

.footer-social {
    display:block;
}

.footer-social li {
     float:left;
}


.footer-social a {
    font-family: @lato-font;
    font-weight: @footer-font-weight;
    font-size: @footer-font-size;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
    padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
}

.footer-social a:hover {
    color: @main-link-hover;
    background-color: @nav-font-background;
}


.footer-info {
    display:block;
    font-family: @lato-font;
    font-weight: @footer-font-weight;
    font-size: @footer-info-font-size;
}

.footer-info a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    color:#5F5F5F;
}

.footer-info a:hover {
    color: @main-link-hover;
    background-color: @nav-font-background;

}
```

HTML Footer Code

```
<div class="row"><!--CONTENT-->
    <div class="col-lg-12"><!--12 COLUMNS-->
        <footer><!--FOOOTER-->      
        <section class="footer-social clearfix">
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/jacobnorwooddesign">Facebook</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                     <li><a href="https://twitter.com/jacobonline">Twitter</a></li>
                     <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/jacobnorwood">LinkedIn</a></li>
                </ul>
        </section>

        <section class="footer-info">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="Jacob Norwood Design Copyright">Copyright Jacob Norwood Design 2014</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Phone Number 512.450.4671">Ph. 512.450.4671</a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:work@jacobnorwood.com" title="Email work@jacobnorwood.com">work@jacobnorwood.com</a></li>
            </ul>
                </section>

        </footer><!--FOOOTER-->
    </div><!-- 12 COLUMNS -->
</div><!--CONTENT-->
```

Comment: Your site looks fine to me. What do you want to center exactly?

Comment: You want the top menu to center in the space between your logo and the edge of the screen?

Comment: Sorry. I posted the wrong HTML section code. It is correct now. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're trying to achieve something like this?

[image]

If so, you can add this to your CSS:

```
.footer-social {
  text-align: center;
}
.footer-social li {
  display: inline;
}
.footer-info {
  text-align: center;
}
.footer-info li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Also, for .footer-social li, remove float: left;